# SQL Server DMK password

Tags: sql-server

Where is the SQL Server Database master key (DMK) password stored? Is it stored in master database? in registry?. If the hacker gets hold of the mdf files will he be able to get the password that was used to create DMK?

Comment: Nothing is stored in the clear and the final keys can even reside in HSM modules - hardware encryption devices.

Answer (score 0):

In the `SQL Server` there is [Encryption Hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189586.aspx) - everything is encrypted by something. You can create one `Database Mater Key` in each database in order to protect the certificates, assymetric and symetric keys in it - the `DMK` is used to encrypted them.

> Database master keys are protected by the Service Master Key. The
>   Service Master Key is created by SQL Server setup and is encrypted
>   with the Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI).

[image]

Let's say we have a database backup and restore it to our local instance. If I try to read some of the ecnrypted data, without knowing the `DMK` password in order to encrypt the certificate I am getting the following error:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'I_DO_NOT_KNOW_THE_PASS';

SELECT *, CAST(DecryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID(N'smGK_АSymmetricKey_01'), BufferEncryptedEmail) AS NVARCHAR(444))
FROM SecurityUsersAssimetricKey

CLOSE MASTER KEY
```

> Msg 15313, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The key is not encrypted using
>   the specified decryptor.

So, in my case (when the `DMK` is encrtpyed by password), I can only read the ecnrypted data knowing the password:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'smGK_MasterKeyPassword';

SELECT *, CAST(DecryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID(N'smGK_АSymmetricKey_01'), BufferEncryptedEmail) AS NVARCHAR(444))
FROM SecurityUsersAssimetricKey

CLOSE MASTER KEY
```

In order to protect the whole data, you can check how`backup encryption` is made.

---

If backup encryption is applied, the backup is encrypted using certificate. Without this certificated, the backup cannot be restored. You can store this certificate anywhere you like. Generally, you are right for the brute force - if the database is restored, you can try to brute force the DMK, when you have it, you can read all encrypted columns. But when you cannot restore the database using its backup, you can do nothing.

Comment: SQL Server can use HSM modules so that even the service master keys aren't stored on the server

Comment: Yes, but how does the SQL server knows this - "Msg 15313, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The key is not encrypted using the specified decryptor". This means it had saved the DMK password somewhere? and it verifies it is not the same?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Are you using such modules in production? I am wondering of the pros and cons of using such.

Comment: @PraveenBalanagendra: A basic concept in data security is being able to check that a password is correct without storing the password itself. This is typically accomplished by storing a *hashed version* of the password. Then, when someone tries to verify their password later, the user-provided password is hashed in the same manner as the stored one and the two hashed versions are compared for equality. In this way, the actual password isn't stored, but provided passwords can still be verified for correctness.

Comment: @BenThul .. Thanks for making it clear. However, does it also means the password can be determined via some means - brute force attack?

Comment: @BenThul .. This to me also means that .. it doesn't matter the different layers of security in SQL server (SMk, DMK, Keys, Certificate etc). If I have the mdf file and the password of the DMK I will be able to decrypt the encrypted data. Which is as good as password protected mdf file?

Comment: @PraveenBalanagendra You can check `backup encryption` if you are concerned of someone getting your files. Also, after `SQL Server 2016 SP1` the `always encrypted` feature is available in standard edition.

Comment: @gotqn I am trying to understand how the SQL server internals is. Based on the discussion so far in this thread it looks like key/certificate details are stored in the database and the encrypted data can be obtained just by DMK password. If I have the DMK password, decryption logic is simple. So not sure what is the use of SMK, Certificate, ASY, SYM Keys. If by any chance a hacker gets a backup file or mdf file, then there are chances the DMK password can be obtained by some means (brute force etc.). On a very high level it looks like the database is just DMK password protected.

Comment: @PraveenBalanagendra If `backup encryption` is applied, the backup is encrypted using certificate. Without this certificated, the backup cannot be restored. You can store this certificate anywhere you like. Generally, you are right for the brute force - if the database is restored, you can try to brute force the DMK, when you have it, you can read all encrypted columns. But when you cannot restore the database using its backup, you can do nothing.

Comment: @gotqn .. Thanks and appreciate your answer. Would like to mark your comments as answer. I will look into the back encryption mechanism.